# Error al entrar a una screen que existente

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Esta pregunta es sencilla. ¿Alguien me responde que tengo que hacer cuando me pasa lo siguiente?

El comando que ejecuto:

```
screen -r server
```

El error que se presenta:

> There is a screen on:
>               1425.server     (18/12/19 16:28:52)     (Attached)
>       There is no screen to be resumed matching server.

Answer (score 4):

Si lo que necesitas es re-conectarte a un screen el comando a utilizar es:

```
screen -d -r
```

Puedes si tienes mas de un screen, al ejecutar el comando de arriba se listan los nombres de los screen y se puede re-conectar o re-attach con el siguiente comando:

```
screen -d -r <screen-name>
screen -d -r 1425.server
```